# logic error according to whom logic error

Tags: c++, syntax, syntax-error

I have been thinking about this subject for a while, this question came up in the exam and the correct answer does not satisfy me. When a=5 is defined in the conditions of an if block, this may be a logic error, but I may want to return true and perform an assignment. No matter how ridiculous it is to do this in such a simple code, wouldn't only the programmer know if it's a logic error or not? My main question here is which of the error types do you think is in the code below?

```
if(a=5) int a=b+1;
```

a) logical error due to syntax error
b) only syntax error
c) syntax error due to logic error
d) only logic error
e) Both syntax and logic error

I do not think that the errors in this code will trigger each other, so I did b. It's probably e. but iam really confused

Comment: The whole thing is useless so I would go with both.  `if(a=5)` is a syntax error as otherwise just get rid of the `if` if you did not want to check for equality.  `int a=b+1;` creates a local variable to the if statemen and the immediately ends the if statement so the variable is pointless, so logic error.

Comment: It's a silly question that can't be answered with the information given. (Do you have more?). Whether it is a syntax error depends on whether a and b have been declared earlier. (Yeah, there's a ```=``` instead of ```==``` and one ```a``` will shadow/hide the other, so what the code does is presumably not intended, but it will actually compile if ```a``` and ```b``` have been declared earlier: just try ```int main(){ int a=0, b=0;  if ( a = 5 ) int a = b + 1; }```

Comment: `if(a=5)` is syntactically correct but could be typo and most compilers will warn you. `int a=b+1;` will not compile as `b` is not declared (see [mcve]).  If `b` is a built-in scalar type and it compiled then it has no effect as the new variable `a` will be discarded.  If `b` is some class type with an overloaded `operator+` then who knows see [mcve] again.  The question needs some pre-conditions to make complete sense.

Comment: `if (a = 5) something` can be replaced with `a = 5; something`, so I would argue that it shows a logical error on the programmer's part, who apparently expected some conditionality.

Comment: https://onlinegdb.com/gILClvov8 Without any other lines it is just a useless bit of errors. It won't compile so it is a syntax error. There is no logic to speak of yet. Where there any more lines of code in the question?

Comment: TWO logic errors :)

Comment: To add to _"the question needs clarification"_ - if the first `a` in the question is a class type with an overloaded `operator=` that returns a `bool` chosen randomly then it all makes sense ;) .

Comment: Is the question about C or C++? You tagged both, but the answers are different for them: It is a syntax error in C (declaration instead of statement after the if) https://godbolt.org/z/687e7aa51 and a faulty logic in C++ https://godbolt.org/z/687e7aa51

Comment: Kind of funny, with all my experience.. and I would not even know how to properly classify this... other then, it just doesn't make sense as a one liner.

Comment: @lastchance question is just this code content and I no longer look for logic while solving exams. True or false can be written in if, but without the complete code, we don't know whether it even makes sense to write if. yes there are 2 logic errors at the moment :)It's not hard for the teacher to give all the code, I don't know why they do this

Comment: @PepijnKramer Literal nonsense is impossible to classify.

Comment: Above is some misinformation, surprisingly also from highly reputed folks. Let's assume that the _code_ appears in a program where a statement is expected. The `if(a=5)` is not a syntax error, not even when `a` is undeclared (it's an error then, but the syntax is correct). The `int a=b+1;` thereafter is no syntax error in C++, but it is one in C. Now, whether the code has a logic error or not, anyone can judge, but only when regarding the whole program (or at least enough context).

Comment: @mch In the lesson, we are processing c++ under the name of C. As far as I know and have learned, they both have the same syntax. Sorry if I am wrong, I am going to check it out right now. Thanks for the warning.

Comment: If this is the entirety of the C++ code, it contains a logic error, a semantic error, and a syntax error.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was edited to remove the C tag after it was answered for C. It was a low-value question to start, and now it and the answers are muddled.

Comment: @PepijnKramer it's just that, and as you say, you need to see the whole code to say something clear. I can distinguish the difference between logic and syntax errors, but when questions like this come, I think the school is a bit unnecessary, unfortunately. I understand what the teacher is trying to evaluation, but it shouldn't be difficult to give the whole code.

Comment: As Eric hinted, changing the question in such a way that answers you've gotten to the original question becomes incorrect or don't make sense anymore isn't good. Please don't do that.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'm sorry for my misunderstanding, someone in the comments said that it is wrong to open 2 tags as c and c++. He asked which language and I immediately returned to the language I wanted to ask, I was a little panicked because I was new to the forum, I'm so sorry..

Comment: I see. Just look at the answers and see what the change has on them.  @dbush's answer is spot on for C. My answer looks rubbish without C. _"why bring in C into this"_-like.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `a` and `b` are both declared before the line as integers, the answer is that there are two logical errors.

1. ```
   if(a=5)
   ```

   This assigns `5` to `a`. The `if` is therefore not needed since it'll always be `true`.
2. ```
   int a=b+1;
   ```

   This creates a local `a` (shadowing the outer `a`) and assigns a value to it. This `a` goes out of scope directly, rendering the whole definition pointless.

Additionally, in **C**, there's a syntax error in `int a=b+1;` since C needs a statement there and not a declaration. The declaration is fine in **C++** though so if the question is about C++, there are no syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

Given this code, assuming `a` and `b` were previously declared with an arithmetic type:

```
if(a=5) int a=b+1;
```

There is a syntax error because the condition of an `if` must be followed by a **statement**.  The above is instead followed by a **declaration**, and so it fails to compile.

Because the code contains a syntax error it doesn't make sense to talk about whether or not the code has a logical error, as the code needs to be fixed first to address the syntax error.

If the code is changed to replace the declaration with an assignment (which is a statement):

```
if(a=5) a=b+1;
```

This will first assign the value 5 to `a` in the condition, causing the condition to be true and then assign the value of `b+1` to `a`.  This is likely a logic error with the intent of the condition to compare the value of `a` with 5, i.e. it should have been `a==5`:

```
if(a==5) a=b+1;
```

If instead the code is changed to put braces around the declaration, making it part of a *block statement*:

```
if(a=5) { int a=b+1; }
```

We again have the probable issue of `a` being assigned to instead of compared in the condition.  Additionally, in the body of the `if`, a new variable `a` is created and assigned the value of `b+1`.  That variable goes out of scope when the block statement is exited.  Most likely, the variable `a` at the upper scope should have instead been updated:

```
if(a==5) { a=b+1; }
```